# Multiple downvote(s) or upvote(s) reputation cost

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

What happens if you receive, say, 5 upvotes or 5 downvotes (meaning multiple upvotes or downvotes) on a question or answer?

Is your reputation going to reduce only the amount or multiplication of factor?

### Example

Say a person receives 3 downvotes in a question. His/her reputation is 500.

So will this bring down his/her reputation to 498 (-2 for downvote) or 494 ( -2 * 3)?

Comment: 494, every downvote counts as does every upvote

Comment: ok.but is there any limit/restriction.For 100 upvotes it will give 500 points

Comment: Max rep per day is 200 per site. Otherwise, no, there is no limit on rep per question/answer.

Comment: And you can never go below 1 reputation.

Comment: See also: [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/262755) which delineates all of the ways you can gain or lose reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reputation change is per vote.

You ask a question and it gets 6 upvotes and 3 downvotes. The net change in your reputation is

```
6 *  5 = 30
3 * -2 = -6
```

**+24**.

There are some exceptions:

- You can't go below 1 reputation, so no matter how many downvotes a post gets, you'll never go below 1 reputation
- There is a 200-point daily reputation cap. If you get 200 reputation points in one day, any "extra" upvotes that day will count for 0 reputation
- Votes on Community Wiki posts do not award or remove reputation

Comment: Does first exception means that if 1-rep user gets many downvotes and then 1 upvote - his rep will be 6? Or will it be consumed by downvotes amount?